# At which point does Edgar Rice Burroughs' "Tarzan" series change from "adventure fiction" to "science fiction"?

Tags: tarzan, tarzan-of-the-apes

Penned before there was a *science fiction* genre, the first few of the 24 *Tarzan* books written by Edgar Rice Burroughs were tales of adventure. As the series went on, Tarzan began dealing with peoples and inventions the world still has yet to see.

By today's standards, at what point in ERB's Tarzan book series does the series change from "adventure fiction" to "science fiction"?

Comment: Based on a ten-second search, the first Burroughs Tarzan novel with a sci-fi edge appears to be "Tarzan at the Earth's Core". It features a futuristic zeppelin and a polar entrance to a fantastical subterranean world.

Comment: I'd say the first one that goes toward SF is even before Pellucidar.  Opar has human women and men stunted by a strange issue with evolution. I think the SF kicks in with that.

Comment: @Richard I was leaning towards Tarzan and the ant men.

Comment: Surely this is just a subtler version of "identify the genre"; a category that we routinely close.

Comment: @dmckee Have you read any Tarzan books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a cursory reading of the book summaries, I'd say that (assuming you exclude Tarzan's ability to communicate with animals) the first book in the series to openly head into fantasy territory is [*Tarzan the Terrible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarzan_the_Terrible) (1921). It contains dinosaurs and two opposing races of subterranean men (with tails). This was then followed by several other books that contain unexplainedly large versions of common animals.

---

The first book to contain outright **science-fictional** material is probably [*Tarzan and the Ant-Men*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarzan_and_the_Ant_Men) (1924) in which Tarzan not only encounters a civilisation of tiny humans (less than a quarter the size of normal men) but is also **shrunk to their size by one of their scientists, by means of an "apparatus" of indeterminate design:**

> "It was Zoanthrohago who captured you," continued Aoponato, "encompassing your fall by means at once scientific and miraculous. After you bad fallen he caused you to lose consciousness and while you were in that condition you were dragged hither by a score of diadets hitched to a hastily improvised litter built of small trees tied securely one to the other, after their branches had been removed. It was after they had you safely within Veltopismakus that Zoanthrohago  set to work upon you to reduce your stature, using apparatus that he has built himself. I have heard them discussing it and they say that it did not take him long."